# Solve the exponential equation $5^{2x+1}+5^x-4=0$.

Tags: logarithms, quadratics

Solve the equation
$$5^{2x+1}+5^x-4=0$$

I need to solve this equation using logarithms. I am in Year 10 and I am clueless on what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate?" It's part of the equation. And please typeset in MathJax.

Comment: Please see above corrected question

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $t=5^x$ and note that
$$5t^2+t-4=(5t-4)(t+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $y = 5^x$, then the equation becomes

$$5y^2 + y - 4 = 0$$
This is a quadratic equation in $y$, now solve for feasible values of $y$ (you can't have a negative $y$ for example).

Answer (score 1):

The given equation $5^{2x+1}+5^x-4=0$ can be rewritten as $5^{2x}\cdot5+5^x-4=0$

This can be rewritten as $5\cdot(5^x)^2+5^x-4=0$

Substituting $u=5^x$, we get: $5u^2+u-4=0$

Solving for $u$:

$$u=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4\cdot5\cdot(-4)}}{2\cdot5}$$

$$u=\frac{-1\pm9}{10}\implies u=\frac{4}{5} \text{ or }u=-1$$

So,

$$5^x=\frac{4}{5} \text{ or } 5^x=-1$$

But $5^x=-1$ has no solution, so this case is ruled out.

We have only $5^x=\frac{4}{5}$. To solve for $x$, we take the logarithm (say the natural logarithm) on both sides, we get:

$$\ln(5^x)=\ln(\frac{4}{5})$$
$$\implies x\ln(5)=\ln(4)-\ln(5) \implies x=\frac{\ln(4)-\ln(5)}{\ln(5)}$$

The properties used here are:

$\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$, and $\ln(\frac{a}{b})=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What happens to  5⋅(5x)2+5x−4=0
How do we get 5u^2+u−4=0. What happens to the 5 at the start?

Comment: @BND the $5$ stays as it is, and $5^x$ is replaced by $u$.

Comment: Ok. If you don't mind me asking why does the 5 not appear when do substitution of u=5^x

Comment: @BND I am here for helping and sharing ideas, no worries. Look at the second line of my answer, are you satisfied with it? If yes, then replace $5^x$ to be $u$. What will be the equation. If you are not satisfied with the second line, then let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use your knowledge of Laws of Exponents to rewrite the expression
$$5^{2x+1}+5^x-4=0\Rightarrow 5\cdot(5^x)^2+5^x-4=0$$

Then, solve using your knowledge of quadratic equations.

$$
\begin{align*}
0 & =  5\cdot(5^x)^2+5^x-4=0 \\
0 & = (5\cdot 5^x-4)(5^x+1) \\
\end{align*}$$

$$
\begin{align*}
5\cdot 5^x & =4 \\
5^{x+1} & =  4 \\
x+1 &= \log_54 \\
x & =  \log_54-1
\end{align*}$$
or
$$5^x=-1$$
for which there is no real solution.

Comment: The exact value of the one real solution is $\log_54-1$.

Comment: Fine, but I am not sure about $5^x=-1$ This is probably not correct.