# Solve the algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve
>   $$8^ x +7\cdot 2^{x+1} = 7\cdot 4^x +8.$$

What's the best way to do this? Would I like convert to same indices?

Comment: Let $z=2^x$, then solve $z^3+14z=7z^2+8$.

Comment: This question is similar to (but not exactly the same as):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340712/solve-the-exponential-equation-52x15x-4-0/3340726?noredirect=1#comment6876001_3340726.

Comment: Note that $z^3+14z-7z^2-8=(z-1)(z-2)(z-4)$.

Comment: How do we get there. I got to your part @Feng. How do I simplify into that form

Comment: @BND I used a method called “polynomial division”. You can learn it on [this wikihow page](https://www.wikihow.com/Divide-Polynomials). Or maybe [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-polynomials/alg-long-division-of-polynomials/v/dividing-polynomials-1). I can’t assure you that the video is right because I can’t access to it.

Comment: @BND, to solve a degree 3 polynomial, you need to use either a formula, inspection or numerical method. Division alone will not work. You could open another question for this part.

Comment: What is the formula?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I guess you mean $8^x+7  \cdot 2^x+1=7 \cdot 4^x +8$.

If so, put $y=2^x$. Then $y^3+7\cdot y +1 = 7y^2+8$.

Comment: I think that the original equation is fine.

Comment: Why do you guess that?